# How much context switching is too much?

Tags: 14.04, cpu-load, administration

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04 on an Lenovo IdeaCentre d400.
The load average is never under 1.0.
So I started to take a deeper look. I do not find anything that could be responsable for this load. The only thing that seems to be "too high" is the cs value (Context Swichtes).

But how much context swichting is too much?

On my Laptop (lenovo thinkpad x220; Ubuntu 14.04) i've got cs values of over 10k at a load of ~0.8. Only running the system and chrome-browser.

Collecting these numbers using vmstat.

Comment: What does `lscpu` say about how many CPUs you have? As your system has "hyperthreading" that might be interpreted as 2 CPUs - hence a load of 1 corresponds to 0.5 with only one CPU.

Comment: If i remember correctly then the IdeaCentre has one core with hyperthreading. Ive got no access to the system right now. I will post more detailed information when i am back home. So @guntbert you think it isnt interpreted correctly?